# attempt to read property on null in document.php line 250

Tags: wordpress

attempt to read property on null in document.php line 250

```
/**
 * @since 2.0.0
 * @access public
 */
public function get_main_id() {
    if ( ! $this->main_id ) {
        $post_id = $this->post->ID;
```

Comment: Please add some more code and explanation around it to be able to understand what the problem is. This question is not clear enough to be able to answer it.

Comment: since elementor devs dont CARE, you can replace the if with `if ( ! $this->main_id  && $this->post )`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. In my case this ocurr after migration of site to other server with All-in-One WP Migration plugin.

The file with problem is: C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\base\document.php